# imakeidx : create a fancy style with TikZ, with a rectangle with one rounded corner

Tags: formatting, tikz-styles, indexing, makeindex

I am trying to create a nice looking style for my index.

Here is what I have achieved vs. what I want to reach :

Achieved :

[image]

Goal :

[image]

Here is my file tablealphab.ist :

```
heading_prefix "
\\vspace*{0.5cm}
\\nopagebreak\n
\\tikz
\\draw (0,0) [draw=gray, fill=gray] circle (0.35cm) node{" heading_suffix "};
\\tikz
\\draw (0,0) [color=gray, fill=gray] coordinate (a) [bend right=0] to +(4.4cm,0) coordinate (b) [bend right] to +(0,-0.7cm) coordinate (c) [bend right] to (a |- c) [bend right=60] to cycle ;
\\vspace*{0.2cm}
\\nopagebreak\n"

headings_flag 1
symhead_positive "Symboles"
symhead_negative "symboles"
numhead_positive "Nombres"
numhead_negative "nombres"
delim_0 "}\\hspace{0pt},\\hspace{6pt}"
delim_1 "\\hspace{0pt},\\hspace{5pt}"
delim_2 "\\hspace{0pt},\\hspace{4pt}"
delim_t "."
item_0 "\n \\item {\\acasB " 
item_x1 "} \\acasR \\subitem "
item_1 "} \\acasR \\subitem "
item_01 "} \\acasR \\subitem "
```

And the rest of my  code :

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calc}                         
\usepackage{xcolor}                       
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{999999}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric, arrows.meta}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=2, title=Alphabetical Index, 
           options= -s tablealphab.ist]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
This is a test\index{test}, several keywords\index{keywords} will be used which are important and deserve to appear in the Index\index{index}.

Terms can be pretty long, who knows\index{terms can be pretty long, who knows}.

\clearpage

\section{Second section}
This second section\index{section} may include some special word, and expand the ones already used\index{used}. 

\printindex
\end{document}
```

I have managed to get a circle and a one-side-rounded rectangle. But can I get an ellipse and an accordingly distorted rectangle? And how can I reduce the height of my rectangle? And choose its width so as it fills the whole line?

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I know this might not exactly be what you're looking for, but here is what i use (Sorry for german notations, if necessary i can translate them):

```
% Fancy Headings
heading_prefix "
\\nopagebreak\n
\\tikz{%
\\node[rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle west arc=0pt, minimum height=0.7cm,fill=black!20!teal,text=white, drop shadow={opacity=.5,shadow xshift=0pt}](text){\\large\\noindent\\bfseries\\sffamily " % Hier wird der Buchstabe eingefügt
heading_suffix "};
\\draw ([xshift=4mm]text.north east) [color=gray, fill=gray, drop shadow={opacity=.5,shadow xshift=2pt}] coordinate (a) [bend right=0] to ([xshift=5.2cm]text.north west) coordinate (b) [bend right] to +(0,-0.7cm) coordinate (c) [bend right] to (a |- c) [bend right=60] to cycle ;
}
\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag  1 % wir benutzen Überschriften
% Übersetzungen
symhead_positive "Symbole"
symhead_negative "symbole"
numhead_positive "Zahlen"
numhead_negative "zahlen"
% Schönere unterpunkte
item_01 "\n \\subitem$\\bullet$ "
item_1 "\n \\subitem$\\bullet$ "
item_12 "\n \\subsubitem - "
item_2 "\n \\subsubitem - "
delim_0 "\\dotfill" % Punktzeile zwischen Einträgen und Seitenzahlen (Ebene 0)
delim_1 "\\dotfill" % Punktzeile zwischen Einträgen und Seitenzahlen (Ebene 1)
delim_2 "\\dotfill" % Punktzeile zwischen Einträgen und Seitenzahlen (Ebene 2)
delim_r "--" % Trenner zwischen Start und Ende eines Seitenbereiches
suffix_2p "\\,f." % Suffix bei einem bereich aus 2 Seiten
suffix_3p "\\,ff." % Suffix bei einem bereich aus 3 Seiten
```

this produces something like this:
[image: Deonstration of the code]

The nice thing about this solution is that you don't have to worry about the curve changing and it looks clean either way.